# How can i get CLCircularRegion center value in ios 7?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, xcode5, ios6.0

Am Working on Geo-Fence Application .When i was inside the Region log is printing like

Region is - CLCircularRegion (identifier:'10', center:<+13.04392382,+80.18383026>, radius:700.00m).

Here how can i get a center value in IOS 7?

Comment: @Chandu did you see my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Read [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLCircularRegion_class/Reference/Reference.html).

The class `CLCircularRegion` has a property `center`.

```
CLCircularRegion *region = //your region

CLLocationCoordinate2D centerPoint = region.center;
```

Please at least read [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLCircularRegion_class/Reference/Reference.html) before posting a question.

Comment: Application is crashing when i use above code in ios 7.1

Comment: @sabir what is the crash log? What code did you use? Saying "it crashed" is not useful.